# "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when running React tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, frontend

I created the project in React. I tried to run a standard React test which looks like this

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('renders learn react link', () => {
  render(<App />);
  const linkElement = screen.getByText(/learn react/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

I don't make this test. It was created with React project installation. So I tried run this test

```
npm test --all
```

And it displays me error

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

  1 | import React, { useState } from "react";
> 2 | import axios from "axios";
I don't change the standard test and it looks like this requires ('@babel/register');
```

Do you know why? How can I solve my problem and test my React app?